# PHPExcel: How to set multiple levels of grouping?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have a problem. Currently I am working on excel reports and I can't set multiple levels of grouping.
One level working perfectly, but next level overwritting existing one:

**WHAT I WANT**

[image: WHAT I WANT]

**WHAT I GET**

[image: WHAT I GET]

Can someone help me? I tried changing levels from 1-3 or 3-1 and still ca't get satisfied results.

```
if (!$this->checkIfCellIsEmpty()) {
                        if ((false === $firstUser) && ($group1 !== $userGroup->getId()) && ($group2 !== $userGroup->getId())) {
                            $this->groupRow(3);
                        }

                        if (($group1 !== $userGroup->getId()) && ($group2 !== $userGroup->getId())) {
                            $this->groupRow(2);
                        }

                        if ($group2 !== $userGroup->getId()) {
                            $this->groupRow(1);
                        }
}
```

where function groupRow is:

```
private function groupRow($level = 1) {
    $this->getPhpExcel()->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($this->getCurrentRow())->setOutlineLevel($level)->setVisible(false)->setCollapsed(true);

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Not without seeing your code...

Comment: @MacroMan added :)